# How to give the repository URL in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am new to Tortoise SVN. I have created a repository in my machine. To access this folder in a remote host, what's the repository url which should be given in SVN checkout? Should the server be running, when I try to access the repository ?

Comment: Is your machine in the same local network as the remote host?

Comment: No, they are in two networks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the server must be running in order for you to access Subversion.

The URL depends on how you've configured Subversion.

My local Subversion instance URL looks like this:

```
svn://localhost:3690
```

Another that I use to access Sourceforge looks like this:

```
https://mandelbrotset.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mandelbrotset
```

It could be http instead of https, depending on how you've set things up.

In general, the URL takes this form:

```
http://host:3690/repository
```

Have a look at the [Red Bean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) if you get stuck.

Comment: I managed to list the repositories within my apache by using an alias and some svn-configuration. I can access the list (and checkout/update/comit/etc.) via http://localhost/svn - where svn is not a real directory on the server.