# Tortoise SVN URL?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Myself and another person want to work on same file in different location.
From google I get to know about version control tool Tortoise svn.
What I understood from tutorials is svn checkout will be created in local and will be sent to repository URL through svn commit, another or n number of persons can check out the same using repository URL then he can also make changes and can commit.
Am I right here?

And when I click on SVN Checkout it is asking for URL of Repository, what is that?
What URL should I use? How to get that?
When I click OK, I am getting following error:

```
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL  
Error:  'svn://myproject/repository/project/trunk'  
Error: Unknown hostname 'myproject
```

I am doing something wrong, can anybody help me how to resolve this? Mainly url.
Thanks

Comment: All the info you need can be found in the manual: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: Do you have a svn repository? if so, is it local or on any other server? how where you doing check-in check-out so far.. meanwhile you can see http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html

Comment: you can refer this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504064/how-to-give-the-repository-url-in-tortoise-svn?rq=1

Comment: I created repository in my local Desktop, Now i want that to be checked out in another Desktop in different location. I have no link with server. When I tried to checkout in different place in same Desktop it works when the path is given. If it is in another Desktop in another location we should

Comment: I created repository in my local Desktop, Now i want that to be checked out in another Desktop in different location. I have no link with server. When I tried to checkout in another location of same Desktop it works when the repository path is given. If it is a  Desktop of another location we should use some url to upload  repository? I seen in tutorials everyone is using some different url, I don't know where they are getting it. Eg:[link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-and-TortoiseSVN-and-Make-Your-First-Repository-Change) Step 10

Comment: If you have "no link with server", you can't share it between desktops, just like you can't copy files between two computers without some sort of network connection. If that's not clear, you may need to learn a few other things before you start worrying about source code. The "some URL" is the URL to the server *you set up* to hold your repository; it's not just some magic spot that appears.